# How to use Ngxs in a standalone component?

Tags: angular, ngxs, angular-standalone-components

Is it possible to use Ngxs in a standalone component?  I've tried importing the `NgxsModule` in the following ways:

```js
@Component({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    NgxsModule.forFeature([MyState]),
...
```

and

```js
@Component({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    NgxsModule.forRoot([MyState]),
...
```

But both give me the following error message: `Type 'ModuleWithProviders<NgxsFeatureModule>' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any>'` (or `NgxsRootModule` in the `forRoot` case).  A more in-depth error message is available as well: `'imports' contains a ModuleWithProviders value, likely the result of a 'Module.forRoot()'-style call. These calls are not used to configure components and are not valid in standalone component imports - consider importing them in the application bootstrap instead.`

Is this supported and I have the syntax wrong?  Or is this not supported?  If not supported, what's the blocker?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

yes it is supported.

As you can see in the [Angular standalone component guide](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components):

> The standalone bootstrap operation is based on explicitly configuring a list of Providers for dependency injection. However, existing libraries may rely on NgModules for configuring DI. For example, Angular’s router uses the RouterModule.forRoot() helper to set up routing in an application.

So you can solve the problem in the same way as they solve it for the router. Edit the `app.config.ts` file:

```html
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
      importProvidersFrom(NgxsModule.forRoot([MyState])),
    // ...
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I had been getting the following NullInjectorError in my JS console until I did this.  

```
"No provider for InjectionToken ROOT_OPTIONS!"
```

Answer (score 28):

#### forRoot()

You can use `importProvidersFrom()` from `'@angular/core'` `NgxsModule.forRoot()` inside your bootstrap function (same as SilasDerProfi wrote before me)

Inside your main.ts:

```
bootstrapApplication(
  AppComponent,
  {
    providers: [
      importProvidersFrom(
        NgxsModule.forRoot(
          [MyState, SidebarState, CoreState],
          {
            developmentMode: !environment.production,
            selectorOptions: {
              suppressErrors: false,
              injectContainerState: false
            }
          }
        ),
        NgxsResetPluginModule.forRoot(),
        // devtools always last
        NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule.forRoot()
      )
    ]
    
  }
).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

#### forFeature() / in lazy loaded:

You can set your lazy Loaded `forFeature([FooState])` while you are declaring your routes.

[See official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#providing-services-to-a-subset-of-routes), or there is an example of lazy loaded routes:

```
import { importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';

export default <Routes>[
  {
    path: '',
    loadComponent:
      () => import('./foo-list/foo-list.component')
        .then(mod => mod.FooListComponent),
    providers: [
      importProvidersFrom(
        NgxsModule.forFeature([FooOverviewState])
      )
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'add',
    loadComponent:
      () => import('./foo-item-add/foo-item-add.component')
        .then(mod => mod.FooItemAddComponent),
    providers: [
      importProvidersFrom(
        NgxsModule.forFeature([FooState])
      )
    ]
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    loadComponent:
      () => import('./foo-item-edit/foo-item-edit.component')
        .then(mod => mod.FooItemEditComponent),
    providers: [
      importProvidersFrom(
        NgxsModule.forFeature([FooState])
      )
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand this thread might be a bit outdated, but for anyone new to this question, I want to mention that we've already developed standalone APIs. However, they haven't been released under a stable version yet. You can install the dev version, which is published from any commit to the master branch, for example, `3.8.2-dev.master-6740f55`.

Those APIs are `provideStore` and `provideStates`. They both return environment providers and are intended to be used in the `ApplicationConfig` when bootstrapping the app and as `Route` providers:

```
import { provideStore } from '@ngxs/store';
import { withNgxsLoggerPlugin } from '@ngxs/logger-plugin';
import { withNgxsRouterPlugin } from '@ngxs/router-plugin';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideStore([ ...states ], withNgxsLoggerPlugin(), withNgxsRouterPlugin())
  ]
});

// features
import { provideStates } from '@ngxs/store';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'pandas',
    loadComponent: ...,
    providers: [
      provideStates([PandasState])
    ]
  }
];
```

If you still have feature modules, you can import them into components. However, you will need another module to import the NGXS module with providers:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [NgxsModule.forFeature([SearchAssistantState])],
})
export class SearchAssistantDataAccessModule {}

@Component({
  ...,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ SearchAssistantDataAccessModule ]
})
export class SearchAssistantComponent {}
```

his can be also done multiple times if this state is required in different places since NGXS states are not duplicated even if you call `forFeature` with the same state many times.